# onclick for checkbox returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView where a column is a checkbox. In the database these checkboxes are dafaulted to one. So if the user unticks the checkbox I call a web method to update the database.

GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRTDetails" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID" ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Checklist Items"></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Checked" HeaderText="OK"></asp:BoundField> 
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                lookupCVRT work = (lookupCVRT)e.Row.DataItem;
                GridView gv = sender as GridView;             

                e.Row.Attributes.Add("ID", "gvCVRTDetails_" + work.ID);
                e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "event.stopPropagation();");

                HtmlGenericControl lnkShowHide = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("lnkShowHide");
                HyperLink ChecklistItem = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("ID");

                bool bAll = work.Checked;
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "<input type=\"checkbox\" " + ((bAll) ? "checked" : "") + "/>";
                e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes.Add("onclick", "UpdateCheckedBox(" + work.ID.ToString() + ", this.Checked);");
            }
        }
```

Javascript function:

```
function UpdateCheckedBox(ID, Checked) {
        alert(Checked);
        PageMethods.UpdateCheckUserControl(ID, Checked, OnUpdateSuccess, OnUpdateFail);
    }
```

But calling `this.Checked` is returning undefined instead of true or false. I also tried `this.Value` but that doesn't work either

Comment: It's `.checked` and `.value`

Comment: @Andreas remove the word this?

Comment: No. JavaScript is also case-sensitive and the properties start with a lowercase letter -> `this.checked` and `this.value`

Comment: @Andreas I tried using checked and value but it is still returning undefined

Comment: The `onclick` is defined on the cell and not on the checkbox. Therefor `this` is the cell and not the checkbox. Either define the `click` handler on the checkbox or change `this.checked` to something to find/get the input from the cell (depending on what `cell` is `this.children[0].checked` or `this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked` could work)

Comment: @Andreas I tried using this.children[0].checked (with the correct cell number) but that didn't work. I am not sure what to put into `this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked`. Is that the datafield from the boundfield in the grid?

Comment: Check the update from @Hermal. This should work but you have to remove the line where you add the `onclick` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You should change the last line to following

```
 e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes.Add("onclick", "UpdateCheckedBox('" + work.ID.ToString() + "', this.checked);");
```

Because if you don't cover `quotes` around `work.ID.ToString()`, it will be treated as a variable there and its wrong. Also as others suggested, use `checked` instead of 'Checked'.

**UPDATE**

```
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "<input onclick=UpdateCheckedBox('" + work.ID.ToString() + "', this.checked) type=\"checkbox\" " + ((bAll) ? "checked" : "") + "/>";
```

Comment: It is still returning undefined

Comment: Let me give you a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/ukom74mv/4/, I am assuming that onclick is being generated correctly, in this fiddle, it is giving me correct alert.

Comment: Yes I understand the example but it is not exactly like my code. Like Andreas said his comment under my question: The onclick is defined on the cell and not on the checkbox. Therefor this is the cell and not the checkbox.

Comment: Correct, then you can change the code as shown in my update

Comment: but using this.checked returns undefined

Comment: It is not calling the javascript function anymore. I can untick the checkboxes but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Can you check for any console errors?Also see the generated HTML of checkbox in inspect element.

Comment: Also remove `;` from end in `onclick`

Comment: getting this error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }. I removed the `;` but still getting this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103727/discussion-between-hemal-and-user123456789).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is changing from the checkbox from `boundfield` to `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="OK?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Checked")) %>'  ></asp:CheckBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the code behind use:

```
CheckBox chkChecked = e.Row.FindControl("chkChecked") as CheckBox;
chkChecked.Attributes.Add("onclick", "UpdateCheckedBox(" + work.ID.ToString() + ", this.checked);");
```

Much easier to select the checkbox instead of the cell like I was trying to do.